# Diferença entre horas sem levar em consideração a data

Tags: sql, query

Boa noite,

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
WITH
CONSULTA AS (
 SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    V.DATA,
    MAX(V.BATIDA) AS MAXBATIDA,
    MIN(V.BATIDA) AS MINBATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW  AS V                            
        WHERE
          V.CODCOLIGADA = 1
           AND  BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
           AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
             GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                       V.DATA
),
CONSULTASEQ AS (
SELECT *, SEQ= ROW_NUMBER() OVERPARTITION BY CHAPA ORDER BY DATA)
  FROM CONSULTA
)
SELECT 
        C1.CHAPA,  
        C1.MAXBATIDA,
        C2.MINBATIDA, 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, C1.MAXBATIDA, C2.MINBATIDA) AS HORAS,
        'TESTE DE HORAS' AS DESCRICAO
  FROM CONSULTASEQAS C1
       LEFT JOIN CONSULTASEQ AS C2 ON C1.CHAPA = C2.CHAPA AND C1.SEQ = C2.SEQ -1
             WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,  C1.MAXBATIDA, C2.MINBATIDA) < 11 
                         ORDER BY C1.MAXBATIDA ASC
```

Ele me retorna:

```
8636;2016-06-04 22:31:00.000;2016-06-06 12:59:00.000;38;TESTE DE HORAS
9042;2016-06-04 22:31:00.000;2016-06-06 12:28:00.000;38;TESTE DE HORAS
9035;2016-06-04 22:32:00.000;2016-06-06 13:31:00.000;39;TESTE DE HORAS
```

No campo horas ele esta calculando a diferença entre a máxima de uma hora com a minima de outra, mais preciso que em campos como esse:

```
8636;2016-06-04 22:31:00.000;2016-06-06 12:59:00.000;38;TESTE DE HORAS
9042;2016-06-04 22:31:00.000;2016-06-06 12:28:00.000;38;TESTE DE HORAS
```

Eu preciso que retorne a diferença das horas sem considerar a data, exemplo:

```
 DIFF ENTRE 22:31:00  E  12:59:00 SEJA:

22:31
23:31
00:31
01:31
02:31
03:31
04:31
05:31
06:31
07:31
08:31
09:31
10:31
11:31
12:31
12:56
```

Ou seja, sem comparar as datas, isso seria possivel ?

SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Sugestão: marcar também como sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma bem simples é assim:

```
select CAST((C1.MAXBATIDA-C2.MINBATIDA) as time(0)) Horas
```

Veja esse exemplo:

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
set @d1='20161024 21:18:41.330'
set @d2='20161024 23:28:41.330'
select CAST((@d2-@d1) as time(0)) Horas
```

Comment: Perfeito,Obrigado.